# Auto complete making MVC table results visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a table generated from an mvc model. Each country has an ID, name and capital. All elements in the table have their visibility set to be hidden.

```html
<table id="countryTable"> 
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Countries.Count; i++)
    {
      <tr id="@Model.Countries[i].id" style="visibility: hidden">
        <td>@Model.Countries[i].Name</td>
        <td>@Model.Countries[i].Capital</td>
      </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I have an auto complete function where I have been trying to make the result of the auto complete make the corresponding row visible again. So if I search "United states" the row for the united states will appear.

```js
$(function () {

    var countries = [];
    @foreach (var country in Model.Countries)
    {
        ... Assign to the array
    }

    $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        search: function (event, ui) {
            $('#countryTable').empty();
            var countryId = ui.item.value;
            document.getElementById(countryId).style.visibility = 'hidden';
        },
        source: countries,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var countryId = ui.item.value;
            document.getElementById("" + countryId + "").style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="autocomplete">
```

Currently the error I am getting is "Cannot read property 'style' of null". I don't think the auto complete is able to find the elements but the IDs are unique. I'm not even sure if this is a good approach so any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: if you `console.log(ui.item.value)` does it give you the expected id?  Should it not be `ui.item.id`?

Comment: Also this is a good way to do the autocomplete using mvc - make a jsonresult method in a controller and return the results you want, rather than showing and hiding table rows: http://www.itorian.com/2013/02/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-json-in-mvc.html

Comment: Hi sorry for the confusion. When creating the countries array I assign id to value. But I tried console.log(ui.item.value) and it does bring back to correct value.

Comment: That jsonresult method would also work but I would prefer to not have to press enter while searching just for the results to be appearing straight away.

Comment: are you sure the element exists then as your error seems to point to the fact that `document.getElementById(countryId)` is null.  Could you paste your rendered html and js into a snippet or fiddle

Comment: I just checked through the console. In the HTML my table is there but no rows are appearing inside it. Is style="visibility: hidden" an incorrect way of making a row still exist just be hidden?

Comment: Try `style="display:none"`

Comment: `.empty()` *Remove all child nodes of the set of matched elements from the DOM* - so the first thing you do on search is **delete** all the rows...

Comment: @freedomn-m hahaha, I was wondering why that `empty()` was there but thought it must have been for something else

Comment: Try changing `$("#countryTable").empty()` to `$("#countryTable tr").hide()`   [Edit: looks like this is already handled by the lines below]

Comment: @Pete could well be - not all the html is shown, so I'm only guessing that the country rows are held in a table with `id='countryTable'`

Comment: As first questions go, this one isn't too bad.  But still, please have a read of this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Specifically on verifiable - the code as provided is not verifiable / repeatable by us, so we have to resort to making guesses.  (which is why you have a lot of comments rather than answers).

Comment: The empty() was there because to my understanding it was to remove any results displayed when nothing was entered but I could be wrong. This is most of the code that I am working with. I have edited it to show the full table with it's id. Unfortunately I can't do an example on jsfiddle because of the mvc model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally gotten the MVC table to display the auto complete results. So I want to give the answer for my question. I decided to make all rows visible and when you search for a country if a country is not part of the auto complete results it becomes hidden. Then if you are not searching anything every country is shown.

The table for displaying the countries hasn't changed much only the style has been removed and a class name added to each row.

```html
<table id="countryTable"> 
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Countries.Count; i++)
    {
      <tr id="@Model.Countries[i].id" class"countryRow">
        <td>@Model.Countries[i].Name</td>
        <td>@Model.Countries[i].Capital</td>
      </tr>
    }
</table>
```

The auto complete function has changed.

```js
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
  search: function (event, ui) {

    var countryToSearch = event.delegateTarget.value.toLowerCase();

    countries.filter(function (value) {
      for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {

        if (countries[i].Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(countryToSearch) <= -1) {
          $('#' + countries[i].value).hide();
        } else {
          $('#' + countries[i].value).show();
        }
      }
    });
  },
  source: countries
})
});
```